# What did the plane mean in Don't Worry Darling?

Tags: plot-explanation, dont-worry-darling

In *Don't Worry Darling*, Alice seeing the plane (pictured below) is the first step in her:

> Finding out the truth, that she was living in a mental simulation

How was this airplane allowed here, as surely this controlled area would not allow such things through?

We are told that "Frank created a better world". So surely in this world, where everything is controlled, there would be no elements that would allow residents to become suspicious of the truth?

[image: Airplane Picture]

Comment: Hi .... I've removed some of the spoiler markup - really we probably don't need any of it, but near the top of the question is more likely to be accidentally exposed, and this contains the main premise of the movie.

Comment: @iandotkelly no problem! Just didn't want to ruin the film for others with accidental spoilers :)

Comment: IMO, the concept of a "controlled area" in the movie is not about living in a mental simulation but rather about living in a highly regulated society where individual freedoms and choices are limited. The presence of an airplane in this controlled area does not necessarily imply that the society is flawed or that residents would become suspicious of the truth.

Answer (score -1):

The wife who killed herself apparently had a lost son, and the theme around that kid was a toy plane, which the camera shots made clear was important to notice. I think the crashing plane signifies the moment the main character subconsciously realised her current reality had major flaws, just as the suicide victim did and died before her eyes, and the baton was passed on, so to speak, so she followed that splinter in her mind to visit the place she's been told not to visit, even though she doesn't know why yet.